# Disable inputs while function bound to change executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a large dynamically created form and want to prevent input values from being changed while the function bound to change executes.  The code below works in Safari, but in IE11 disabling the input element causes loss of focus, so it cancels the future change event.  Therefore every other change is not triggered...

OR is there a better way to implement the functionality I am looking for?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $('ul').append("<input type='text' id='"+i+"' class='required require'>");
}
$('body').on('change','.required', function(evt) {
  ENABLED = $('input').not(':disabled');
  ENABLED.prop("disabled", true);
  $('#results').append($(this).attr('id')+' - '+evt.type+'<br/>');     
  if ($(this).val() != '') { $(this).removeClass('require'); }
  else { $(this).addClass('require'); }
  //more functions that can take some time to complete...
  ENABLED.prop("disabled", false);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8s3h0jcz/7/)